# AJAX requests broken due to HTTPS for wp-admin

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, ssl, https, nonce

I have my wp-admin section forced to HTTPS via a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/). I also have specific pages that are using https on the frontend (login, billing, etc.)

I seem to be having an issue with HTTP pages using AJAX to HTTPS for admin-ajax.php the nonce fails. Is it possible to use HTTP nonce with HTTPS nonce? HTTPS to HTTPS works fine. The issue is only HTTP to HTTPS. Is this expected behavior?

I don't see a need to provide any code as this is pretty standard.

Thanks for any input

Comment: Are you positive it's the nonce that's failing?

Comment: Absolutely. It fails on `wp_verify_nonce` when I use HTTP to HTTPS. If I use HTTPS to HTTPS it works fine. Also, if I use HTTP to HTTP it works fine too. The issue seems to be across the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to full SSL for everything. Seriously, it's way easier than dealing with mixed content.

Comment: Agreed but due to limitations with our video content player from a contracted third-party, this is not a possibility right now. I am pushing for them to solve their issues because I am wanting to be fully HTTPS. Thanks

Comment: disagree with the "full SSL", as just for logged in users can be enough, but yeh, if you need some HTTPS in the front end than all the front end needs to be HTTPS or you will run into all kind of problems.

Comment: If you already have an SSL certificate, then just use it for everything on the whole site. Dealing with mixed content is a pain, and anyway, Google now likes https URLs better, so you might as well go all-in with it.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using is quite old. I use this one without issues: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/

Comment: I would like to use that one but it does all pages, we have only some pages that need to be HTTPS. Not my choice but that's the way it is, I would prefer all to HTTPS but there are issues with video content on HTTPS pages hence the current setup until the other issues are resolved (outside of my control)